# In bash how do I divide two variables and output the answer rounded upto 5 decimal digits?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic-expressions, bc

I took two variables as input and after dividing them, I want to get the output rounded up to 5 decimal digits. I have tried this way ->

```
sum=12
n=7
output=$("scale=5;sum/n"|bc)
echo $output
```

My code isn't showing any output. What can I do??

**TestCase:**

If `sum=3345699` and `n=1000000` then `(sum/n)=3.345699`, it should be changed into `3.34570`.

Comment: `sum=12; n=7; output=$(bc<<<"scale=5;$sum/$n"); echo $output`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you missed the `echo` (or `printf` or any other thing) to provide the data to `bc`:

```
$ echo "scale=5; 12/7" | bc
1.71428
```

Also, as noted by cnicutar in comments, you need to use `$` to refer to the variables. `sum` is a string, `$sum` is the value of the variable `sum`.
All together, your snippet should be like:

```
sum=12
n=7
output=$(echo "scale=5;$sum/$n" | bc)
echo "$output"
```

This returns `1.71428`.

Otherwise, with `"scale=5;sum/n"|bc` you are just piping an assignment and makes `bc` fail:

```
$ "scale=5;sum/n"|bc
bash: scale=5;sum/n: No such file or directory
```

---

You then say that you want to have the result rounded, which does not happen right now:

```
$ sum=3345699
$ n=1000000
$ echo "scale=5;($sum/$n)" | bc
3.34569
```

This needs a different approach, since `bc` does not round. You can use `printf` together with `%.Xf` to round to `X` decimal numbers, which does:

```
$ printf "%.5f" "$(echo "scale=10;$sum/$n" | bc)"
3.34570
```

See I give it a big scale, so that then `printf` has decimals numbers enough to round properly.

Comment: Don't you have to say `$sum/$n` ?

Comment: @cnicutar absolutely. Thanks, corrected!

Comment: @jbsu32 what values do you give to `sum` and `n` to get `(sum/n)=3.345699`?

Comment: `sum=3345699` and `n=1000000`

Comment: "you are just piping an assignment" I don't think that's exactly what happens : since the string is quoted, it is parsed by `bash` as a single token, and since it's the first token of the expression, `bash` tries to interpret it as a command, which explains the `No such file or directory`

Comment: @jbsu32 `bc` does not perform rounding, it just truncates. You can use `printf` with `%.Xf` to round to X decimals. For example, `printf "%.5f" "$(echo "scale=10;$sum/$n" | bc)"`.

Comment: @fedorqui It works fine! Will you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @jbsu32 sure, I just did it!

Answer (score 1):

`sum` and `n`, these are bash variables. you should add `$` to get their values. So, the solution should be:

```
echo "scale=5;($sum/$n)"|bc
1.71428
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=12;n=7;printf "%0.5f\n", sum/n}'
1.71429
```

In this solution , awk uses `printf` to round up decimal to 5 places.  If you wish to pass bash variables then use following :

```
 awk -v sum=12 -v n=7 'BEGIN{printf "%0.5f\n", sum/n}'
 1.71429
```

On side notes, awk seem to be good in arithmetic :

```
sh-4.1$  time echo "scale=5; 12/7" | bc ;  time echo "scale=5;($sum/$n)"|bc;time awk 'BEGIN{sum=12;n=7;printf "%0.5f\n", sum/n}'
1.71428

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
1.71428

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
1.71429

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
sh-4.1$
```