# Decimal values in bash script becoming all zeros

Tags: linux, bash, bc

This is my first bash script and have ran into a little problem with setting the decimal precision. I have been tasked to create a bash script that calculates the area and circumference of a circle given the diameter of 20. This is what I currently have

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
diameter=$1 # storing first argument 
radius=$(echo "scale=5;$diameter / 2" | bc) # setting radius
# echo "$radius"

# calculate area of a circle
area=$(echo "scale=5;3.14 * ($radius * $radius)" | bc -l) # A = pi(r^2)

# calculate circumference of a circle
circum=$(echo "scale=5;2 * 3.14 * ($radius)" | bc -l) # C = 2(pi)(r)

echo "Circumference: $circum"
echo "Area: $area"
```

When I run the script it prints out

```
Circumference: 62.80000
Area: 314.00000
```

It should be printing out

```
Circumference: 62.83185
Area: 314.15926
```

I am not understand why it is not displaying the correct decimal values. I have given the `scale=5` to display five decimal places which it is doing. I am confused why the zeros are showing up and not the true decimal values. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: radius=$((echo "scale=5;$diameter / 2" | bc)). Try like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343811/in-bash-how-do-i-divide-two-variables-and-output-the-answer-rounded-upto-5-decim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If pi were equal to 3.14, then your code is giving exact results.

To get the exact value of pi in `bc` code, use `4*a(1)`:

```
# calculate area of a circle
area=$(echo "scale=5;4*a(1) * ($radius * $radius)" | bc -l) # A = pi(r^2)

# calculate circumference of a circle
circum=$(echo "scale=5;2 * 4*a(1) * ($radius)" | bc -l) # C = 2(pi)(r)
```

(This works because `a(1)` is the arctangent of 1 which is pi/4.)

With those changes, a sample run looks like:

```
$ bash circ.sh 20
Circumference: 62.83120
Area: 314.15600
```

The limited precision now is due to the choice of `scale=5`.

#### Still better precision

The code below keeps the best precision around until it is time to print and then prints in your desired precision:

```
#!/bin/bash
diameter=$1 # storing first argument 
radius=$(echo "$diameter/2" | bc -l) # setting radius

# calculate area of a circle
area=$(echo "4*a(1)*$radius^2" | bc -l) # A = pi(r^2)

# calculate circumference of a circle
circum=$(echo "2 * 4*a(1) * $radius" | bc -l) # C = 2(pi)(r)

printf "Circumference: %.5f\n" "$circum"
printf "Area: %.5f\n" "$area"
```

Example:

```
$ bash circ.sh 20
Circumference: 62.83185
Area: 314.15927
```

Comment: Thank you @John1024 it did not even cross my mind that I was representing `pi` wrong.